# float object is unsubscriptable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to set all the `num_of_cells` values to the `N` and `Q` values calculated with this code:

```
import numpy as np

source_Q = 4
source_N = 9999.0
delta_t = 6
time = delta_t / float(3600)
delta_x = 50 * time
num_of_cells = np.int(1.25 / delta_x) + 1
N = 180 * delta_x
Q = 3000 * time
normal_cell_capacity = float(2400) / float(120)
incident_cell_capacity = float(600) / float(120)

for i in range (1, num_of_cells):
    Q = Q[i+1]
    N = N[i+1]
```

This error is produced:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is unsubscriptable
```

Comment: Presumably on the line `Q = Q[i+1]`, so... what *did* you expect that to do?

Comment: `Q` is just a float variable, and not as list. Hence, it cannot be subscripted. That's also what the error message tells you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I am trying to assign the Q and N values to each num_of_cells, of which there are 15.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Do you mean you want e.g. a *list* of `Q` and `N` values?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant

Comment: But you don't *have* a list, and if you did it probably wouldn't be called e.g. `Q`, and you would probably want to assign to the index (`some_list[i] = some_value`) rather than vice versa. I think you need to review this carefully from the top.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I apologize this might be confusing as I am quite new to python programming.

Comment: Invite me to chat so maybe I can help directly with your first steps...